# How can we use minimatch in powershell?

Tags: powershell, minimatch

I would like to be able to get all the files using a pattern like `c:\files\**\bla\**\*.ts`, for example.

Possible options, sorted in the order of preference, are:

1. Powershell supports it already. (How???)
2. There is a powershell module implementing it.
3. There is a .Net library that does it. [glob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glob/) and [minimatch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Minimatch/) look promising.
4. There is a windows command line tool that does it.

I am asking this question because I prefer the first 2 options, but so far (10 mins) I came up empty.

Comment: `dir c:\files???.ts`

Comment: Oops, I have not noticed that SO botched the stars in `c:\files\**\*.ts`. I fixed it now. dir treats `**` as `*`, which is not correct for minimatch.

Comment: Would that be like `dir -r c:\files *.ts`?

Comment: That one - yes. How about `c:\files\**\bla\**\*.ts` ? Or anything more involved?

Comment: [Seems like](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/44) it currently can't.
`dir` or `Get-ChildItem` command accepts wildcards. See [this page](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2015/01/23/the-wonderful-world-of-filtering-and-globbing/)

Comment: I solved it by cheating, since Powershell can run C# code. I download and use a NuGet package that handles minimatch.